# Green file names and folders after backing up data in Linux

Tags: permissions, directory, colors

I've recently wanted to switch from Fedora to Ubuntu and after backing up my data to an external hard drive, installing Ubuntu and moving them back I encountered an unpleasing appearance.

All of my files are green (they have all permissions for user, groups, others) whether they are executables, pdfs, text and so on. Same applies for directories and they're shown with a blue font and green background.

The issue isn't really the coloring as I "just" need to restore the files to their original rights, but how could I do this effectively ?

In the best case scenario, what I think would be the best to do would be to remove all executable rights on all the files with extensions but even with solution I think a lot of other binaries could have extensions, if so I don't know which.

I guess the green coloring isn't the worse, but mostly the fact that the folders are awful to read.

[This is the kind of folder colors I would try to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76g6F.png)

I tried playing with chmod recursively, removing "others" rights but other kind of coloring keeps appearing, and regarding the executable/or not files colors, I'm not sure at all how to (if possible) to do.

Comment: Why talk about colors? It are the permissions probably that you want to change. To restore file permissions properly, they must have been properly stored in the backup in the first place. Provide concise info on how you backed up, how you restored, what the file systems are on your backup (unless you used tar), and delete some information on the colors to make the post shorter and more concise.

Comment: The thing is I simply dragged and dropped files like I usually do I never had issues, I find it weird it restored everything to 777 and why it did that in the first place. (without tar zip etc...)

Comment: If the external filesystem is NTFS or FAT, then you have lost any of the original permissions.

Comment: oh well this explains it all. It's no big deal but still is a pain to read, I'll try at least changing some rwx values for directories in order to see them better. thanks for the precisions.